# High-velocity collision tests between points and triangles

Tags: collision, detection, point

I'm running a very simple particle simulation where I move particles around in space.

Particles are represented as simple 3D points in space, and their movement is achieved by incrementing their position with a velocity vector (newPos = oldPos + velocity).

I'd like to introduce a form of collision detection where particles can bounce off 3d triangles (simple surfaces defined by three 3D points). A naive approach is to just shoot a ray off each particle in the direction of their velocity vector, with a length of the velocity magnitude of the particle, and if a ray-triangle intersection is detected, go from there to calculate particle reflection vector, etc.

However...if both particles and triangles are moving over time, there are lots of cases where collisions should occur, but that naive approach will fail to detect them. For example, imagine a slow moving particle approaching a fast moving triangle. At a particular simulation step the ray shot out of the particle along its trajectory may not reach a triangle ahead of it...but by the next simulation step the triangle might move so fast that it moves behind the particle and the collision is missed.

Is there a standard way to detect point-triangle collisions that can account for these types of problematic cases? Increasing simulation substeps is of course an option, but not a preferred one since it merely reduces the possibility of a missed collision, rather than preventing them entirely.

Comment: Are the triangles rotating, or just translating?

Comment: @PaulBentley Ideally they could be rotating or even deforming.